# I want to show that city weather information that I selected from the drop-down, how can I manage it?

Tags: html, css, json, api

I want to show that city weather information that I selected from the drop-down, how can I do this through json? I am getting that city through Jquery
when selected I just want to know how can I load the city weather information?

> index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="weather-container" style="background:#ccc;text-align:center">
            <img src="" alt="" class="icon">
                <p class="city"></p>
                <p class="weather" style="font-size: 22px;margin:0"></p>
                <p class="temp" style="font-size: 60px;margin:0;font-weight:bold"></p>
                <select name="" class="select_city" id="">
                    <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
                    <option value="Karachi">Karachi</option>
                    <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
                    <option value="Perth">Perth</option>
                    <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
                </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

> script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.select_city").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        alert("You have selected the country - " + selectedCountry);
    });
});
var cityy = "Lahore";
$.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + selectedCountry + "&units=metric&APPID=d89208ad904d31a4402384ff1d4d1a2f", 

function(data){
    console.log(data);

    var icon = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
    $('.icon').attr("src", icon);

    var temp = Math.round(data.main.temp);
    $('.temp').append(temp);

    var weather = data.weather[0].main;
    $('.weather').append(weather);

    var city = data.name;
    $('.city').append(city);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "var selectedCountry" as a global variable so that it should be available to other functions. An issue with scope and context.

Define it like:
 var selectedCountry = null;

then in document.ready allocate the value without using var keyword.

selectedCountry = selected values through Javascript